# jquery datatable not working after data updation

Tags: jquery, django-templates

I am using ListView to list a datatable inside a div element. In the parent page, i am using jquery .load() to load the ListView template inside the div. If i delete an entry in the table using an ajax call and reload the table by calling the ListView using the .load() , the table loses its datatable feature ( it is listed as normal table not datatable, no pagination etc.). I suspect that im missing something in the second ajax call.

My ListView template with datatable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
 <table class="table vr-mdl" id="contable">
                             <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="th-one">
                                   <button class="ml-10 bl-btn no-br no-lh np-col btn btn-sm btn-default-imp-white add-filter-btn" id="contactTabelView">
                                    <i class="material-icons v-sub">add</i>
                                   </button>
                                  </th>
                                  <th class="th-two">Basic Info</th>
                                  <!-- <th class="th-three">Company</th> -->
                                  <th class="th-four">Tags</th>
                                  <!-- <th class="th-five">Lead Score</th> -->
                                  <th class="th-six">
                                   <button class="bl-btn no-br no-lh np-col btn btn-sm btn-default-imp-white add-filter-btn" id="contactTabelView">
                                    <i class="material-icons v-sub">chevron_left</i>
                                   </button>
           <button class="bl-btn no-br no-lh np-col btn btn-sm btn-default-imp-white add-filter-btn" id="contactTabelView">
            <i class="material-icons v-sub">chevron_right</i>
           </button>
          </th>
                              </tr>
                             </thead>
                     <tbody id="list_contact_here" >
            {% for u in object_list %}                              
                              <tr class="odd-tr">
                                  <td>
                                   <label class='custom_check_container'>
                                    <input type='checkbox' class='select-all-radio a-c-b contact_ch' value="{{u.id}}" name='contact_checked'>
                                    <span class='custom_check'></span>
                                   </label>
                                  </td>

                                  <td class='slct_prfl' data-href="{% url 'contacts:view_profile' id=u.id %}">
                <img class='thumb-sm img-inital img-circle' title='Customer Success Team' data-name='CT' src='https://www.agilecrm.com/icons/service.svg' alt=''>
                <p>{{ u.first_name }}<br><small style='font-size:11px;'>mail</small>
                </p>
             </td>

                                  <td>
                                   <span class="contact_tag label bg-light dk text-tiny m-r-2 tags-l-h">Sample</span>
                                  </td>

                                  <td class='edit_option_contact'>
                                   <a class='contact-td-more dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>
                                    <i class='material-icons'>more_horiz</i>
                                   </a>
                                   <ul class='contact-more-options dropdown-menu dropdown-menu1 pull-right' role='menu'>
                                    <li><a href='#' class='contact-more-edit'><i class='material-icons'>mode_edit</i><span>Edit</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href='#' class='contact-more-delete ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>delete</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Delete</span></a>
                                    </li>
                   <li><a href='#' class='contact-more-send-mail ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>email</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Send Email</span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href='#' class='schedule-appoinment ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>date_range</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Schedule an appointment</span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href='#noteModal' class='contact-more-add-note  ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>note_add</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Add Note</span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href='#' class='contact-more-add-event  ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>event</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Add Event</span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href='#' class='contact-more-add-deal  ignore-tr-click'><i class='material-icons ignore-tr-click'>monetization_on</i><span class='ignore-tr-click'>Add Deal</span></a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
             </td>
                              </tr>
           {% endfor %}
                             </tbody>
                         </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#contable').dataTable({
        "pageLength": 5,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "searching": false
     });

} );
</script>
```

and the ajax call in the parent template.

```
function list_conts(){
    var url="{% url 'contacts:contlist'%}";
    $("#con_table").load(url);

   }
```

How do i load it again? Many thanks for the helps.

Comment: Do you recieve any errors in the console? This seems like a typo in #con_table in function list_conts

Comment: Yh, im receiving a jquery.Deferred exception ....datatable is not a function and  Uncaught typeerror....datatable is not a function.

Comment: You have `id="contable"` in your HTML and you are loading data into `con_table` (there's no underscore)

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr  Im sorry, i didn't post the parent page. The con_table id belongs to a div element in the parent page where im loading the table (above HTML).

Comment: Well in your template, init DT outside document.ready(). `load()` will not execute code inside it

Comment: Also, include DT js in parent page. load () will not include this script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you lost your DataTable functionality, there should be an error in the console, which was the cause.
You have configured DataTable successfully after document.ready().
Then, you lose it when you attempt to load again and receive a console error.

For reloading data, DataTable has its internal reload() function, which should be used for refreshing data while keeping the setup you provided when your DataTable was initiated.

However, you can do a workaround, by calling the same DataTable setup function that you already have. Just repeat it when your lisview reload finishes. It will recreate the whole datatable object.

Comment: The console gives the errors i've posted above(question comment). I'll try it the datatable way and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @SayYes - Hi, have you had any chance to check my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include DT library in main page and don't use `$(document).ready()` in template. Code inside this block won't execute with Ajax.

Alternatively, init your DT in load event callback. In any case, DT js file should be available in main file and not in template.

P.S: I'm on phone app, so don't mind the brevity of answer